# Converting 2d array to cv::Mat in C++ seems to fail for 1024x1024 images in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array

I have 2 images: A 1024x1024 image, and a 1022x1023 crop of it:

[image]

[image]

the following code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::cout<<"running Lenna..\n";
    cv::Mat mat = imread("lena1022_1023.bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );


    mat.convertTo(mat, CV_64FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
    int A=mat.rows; int B=mat.cols;
    double arr2D[A][B];
    
    //convert mat to 2D vec
    std::vector<double> arr;
    arr.assign((double*)mat.data, (double*)mat.data + mat.total());
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec2D;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        auto first = arr.begin() + (mat.rows * i);
        auto last = arr.begin() + (mat.rows * i) + mat.rows;
        std::vector<double> vec0(first, last);
        vec2D.push_back(vec0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<A; i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0; j<B; j++)
        {
            arr2D[i][j] = vec2D[i][j];
        } 
    }

    cv::Mat final1(A,B, CV_64FC1, arr2D);
    std::cout<<"final1: "<<final1.rows<<", "<<final1.cols<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It works for the 1022x1023 image, but if I use `imread` on `lena1024.bmp` which is a 1024x1024 image, then I get a segfault error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is this?

**EDIT**

I replaced `double arr2D[A][B];` with

```
double** arr2D = new double*[A];
for(int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    arr2D[i] = new double[B];
```

I also outputted `final1` at the end with

```
final1.convertTo(final1, CV_8UC3, 255.0);
cv::imwrite("lena1024-final.bmp", final1);
```

The result is:
[image]

It should look like the original input image. How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe your bug is here: `double arr2D[A][B];` VLAs have a limited space because they are allocated on the stack. The default of some compilers is 8MB.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: I replaced it with a dynamic array as mentioned in the `EDIT`. The resulting image doesn't match the original one